# How do I get blobs metadata on ASP.NET Core 2.1? FetchAttributes method looks like being not implemented

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

I am trying to retrieve some cloud objects from Azure Blob storage and I need to access their metadata. When doing so on .Net Standard framework, I can use the following method :

```
blob.FetchAttributes()
```

But, it looks like this method is not implemented on .Net Core 2.1 and I can't find any equivalent method in the docs.

Would you have any workaround?

Here is the code (working on .Net Standard but failing on Core) :

```
Dictionary<T, Uri> dic = new Dictionary<T, Uri>();

CloudBlobDirectory directory = container.GetDirectoryReference(cloudLink.BlobFolderName);

foreach (IListBlobItem blobItem in directory.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(null).Result.Results)
{
    if (blobItem is CloudBlockBlob blob)
    {
        blob.FetchAttributes();

        if (blob.Metadata.ContainsKey(DefaultMetadataKey))
        {
            if (blob.Metadata.ContainsKey(DefaultMetadataKey))
                dic.Add(cloudLink.ReadMeta(blob.Metadata[DefaultMetadataKey]), blob.Uri);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use the [async version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob.fetchattributesasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlob_FetchAttributesAsync). And as a sidenote: use proper await instead of calling .Result as in `directory.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(null).Result.Results`

Comment: Thanks @PeterBons. It works like a charm. From the documentation link you sent me, how do you figure out which method is valid for .NET Core and which is not? I couldn't find any logical way to differentiate them by looking at MSDN.

Comment: @XavierAM, If the answer works for you, please help mark it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Hello @PeterBons. Following you remark about the use of a proper await, I transformed the async call to           `var listingResult = await directory.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(null);
            foreach (IListBlobItem blobItem in listingResult.Results)
            { ... }`. Is there any way the foreach can enumerate directly on the awaited method? It's a detail but I'd prefer to get it in one line instead of two (and I am not really proficient yet with asynchronous programming)

Comment: You can do `foreach (IListBlobItem blobItem in (await directory.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(null)).Results) { ... }`

Comment: @PeterBons ok clear. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using the nuget package `WindowsAzure.Storage`, and in that package, there is no syncronous methods for dotnet core, you can refer to this [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/367) for more details.

So if you are using the above nuget package, you should use Async method like `FetchAttributesAsync` instead of `FetchAttributes`.

But now there is new nuget package [Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob/), version 9.4.2, and it supports the syncronous methods(like `FetchAttributes`) for dotnet core.

Please take use of the new package, and the sample code with .net core 2.1 works fine at my side.

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp4netcore
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("xxxxx");

            var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("test-1");
            CloudBlobDirectory directory = cloudBlobContainer.GetDirectoryReference("sub1");
            foreach (IListBlobItem blobItem in directory.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(null).Result.Results)
            {
                if (blobItem is CloudBlockBlob blob)
                { 
                    //the new package supports syncronous method
                    blob.FetchAttributes();

                    foreach (var metadataItem in blob.Metadata)
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine("\tKey: {0}", metadataItem.Key);
                    Console.WriteLine("\tValue: {0}", metadataItem.Value);
                    }
                }

            }            

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are correct, I am using Windows.Storage Nuget package. I was not aware of this issue. Many thanks